# Are there independent research groups?

Tags: soft-question

I wanted to ask if someone knows how to find independent researchers or research groups. I mean, people interested in doing Math in a research level that are not related to universities neither investigation institutes, that freely choose and propose research topics and discuss their own results, with the purpose of (maybe) writing a publishable paper.

Thanks,

Dan

Added comment: For independently I mean that for example some guy is interested in lets say p-adic numbers. So he begins to study them independently and finds some new publishable results. By independent research group I mean a group of guys (not necessarily in the same place or country) interested in lets say, p-adic numbers that share comments and results via email and eventually get a publishable paper. They are independent in the sense that they do not do research in what an entity (university, at&t, etc.) Tells them, but in a topic they share common interest.

Comment: How does an "investigation institute" differ from a "research group"?

Comment: Independent of what?

Comment: I'm guessing he means an institution that is not affiliated with a university.  Something analogous to the Perimeter Institute.

Comment: Abstract-algebra?!? A retag is in order here.

Comment: The distinction he means is to exclude (i) universities, and (ii) bell lab (AT&T) style think tanks who (professionally) produce excellent research in the private sector. Something like hacker spaces, which I doubt exist for publication level research.

Comment: You mean like the October 2011 entry [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/7027/7003)? :-)

Comment: If there are independent research groups, then there should be independent research rings and independent research fields. I am an independent research monoid with a characteristic function which is irrational almost everywhere.

Comment: Something akin to the polymath project?http://polymathprojects.org/

Comment: I think your idea of "independence" is a little bit naive. Generally speaking, at least in pure maths ($p$-adic numbers, if you whish), nobody tells you about what to do your research at the universities. And, as far as I know, even at AT&T you'd be surprised about your freedom for doing the research you want.

Answer (score 5):

One possible place to look might be the National Coalition of Independent Scholars (NCIS) http://www.ncis.org/